# link multiple test cases to one test case

Tags: c#, selenium, tfs, automated-tests

I'm automating test cases  with Visual Studio (Selenium) and want to associate the automations with the test cases on TFS.

The problem is that I can only associate one automation with one test case, while my automations test various test cases.

What I tried was to create a "master" test case and link the related ones to him, but once the result of the master is marked as passed, the children do not change the status.

Is there a way to link an automation with multiple test cases on TFS?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a test Plan or test suite, then add multiple test cases to the test suite or test plan, then run the test suite or test plan.

Please see [Create a test plan and test suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/create-a-test-plan?view=vsts) and [Run automated tests from test plans in the Test hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=vsts) for details.